# iptables - marcação de pacote com redirecionamento para o squid

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables

Eu tenho um firewall com balanceamento de carga através de marcação de pacotes e um squid juntos.

Estou marcando os pacotes para que os meus dois links sejam usados ( gvt e OI )

então o **link1 = gvt** e o **link2 = OI**

Ele já funciona em partes, eu consegui direcionar algumas portas para o link2 assim:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -m iprange --src-range 192.168.1.2-192.168.1.199   -i eth2 -p tcp -m multiport --dport 25,80,3128,443,587,5938  -j MARK --set-mark 2
```

testei e ele saiu pelo link 2, menos a porta 80, esta não saiu pelo link 2. porque abaixo desta regra eu tenho a regra que redireciona para o squid assim:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0  -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3128
```

Mesmo marcando os pacotes das porta 3128 e a 80 eles continuam saindo pelo link 1.

Acho que essa regra acaba desmarcando o pacote, ou alguma coisa parecida, será que alguém consegue me ajudar a ajustar essa regra ou adicionar uma outra para resolver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O redirecionamento da porta 80 para o squid (proxy transparente) significa que os pacotes estao sendo interceptados no firewall e quem faz efetivamente a requisicao http eh o squid em si. Portanto, a regra mangle nao vai se aplicar nessa situacao, jah que ela eh uma regra que se aplica somente a pacotes PASSANDO pelo firewall (i.e. pacotes provindos da rede interna e direcionados para a internet). O que vc precisa eh de uma regra que marque os pacotes providos do firewall (i.e. provindos do squid que estah rodando no firewall). Algo como:

iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp ! -d 192.168.0.0/16 --dport 80 -j MARK --set-mark 2

Observe que o "! -d 192.168.0.0/16" eh importante para evitar que conexoes do squid para um servidor web INTERNO nao seja redirecionada (erroneamente) para a internet. A regra acima vai se aplicar, portanto, somente a conexoes provindas do firewall com porta de destino 80.

Comment: Obrigado, pela regra e principalmente pela explicação, acho que entendi um pouquinho, o PREROUTING e o POSTROUTING sao pacotes que só repassam pacotes antes e depois, só passam pelas placas sem chegar em alguma aplicação do firewall e o FORWARD e OUTPUT seriam chegando e saindo das aplicações?